# Is it reasonable to use a random generated BigInt as a primary key?

Tags: sql-server

My application generates the primary keys for the tables on the client side and so I am restricted from using an identity column. It's not a financial application and a duplicate row once in a million years would not be a problem.

With this in mind would there be any reasons for me not to use bigint as the data type of a primary key?

Comment: I have no idea why this question would be downvoted by someone. It's clear and a legitimate question.

Comment: Are you concerned about using a bigint as a datatype? or using a random value for a primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious downside that comes to mind is disk space. When you use big int vs int you're increasing the size of your records on disk.

If you're expecting to deal with more then 2.1 billion records (which is the limit of int) in the table you have a much larger task then dealing with increased disk space, you're dealing with a very large dataset.

I would take a look into SQL data partitioning.